# How to make the field `slider` display in the products table if it exists?

Tags: laravel

I have a slider field in the products table. That some have value and some don't.

[image: images]

How to make the field `slider` display in the products table if it exists?

```
          $sliders = Product::query()->whereNotNull('slider')->get();
```

Comment: `whereNotNull('sliderr')` So is it named `slider` or `sliderr`?

Comment: I changed it `whereNotNull('slider')` but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is answer of your question

```html
$slider = Product::query()
    ->select(['id', 'name', 'description', 'price', 'slider']) // include the 'slider' field in the select method
    ->whereNotNull('slider')
    ->get();
```

In Blade, Please check below code

```html
@foreach ($products as $product)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $product->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $product->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $product->description }}</td>
        <td>{{ $product->price }}</td>
        <td>{{ $product->slider }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```